# importing python module in colab fails

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I'm importing a test function in colab but it's not working as I would expect. I create a simple `.py` file to test, but I failed to import it despite the fact that I the file can be seen in the path.

```
from google.colab import drive
import sys
import os
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
path="/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/"
sys.path.insert(0,path)
os.chdir(path)
os.listdir(path)

from PPLLM.py import Demo
```

results in the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-eb52ff305968> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from PPLLM.py import Demo

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PPLLM'
```

The pathing seems to work:

```
[...,
'PPLLM.py']
```

The PPLLM file is created in VScode and uploaded to ensure no formatting issues.

The contents are:

```
def Demo():
  pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modules are imported without the extension.

For example, that should fix the issue

```py
from google.colab import drive
import sys
drive.mount('/content/drive', force_remount=True)
path="/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/"
sys.path.insert(0,path)

from PPLLM import Demo
```